# awk get .ini values from config file path

Tags: awk

I am trying to grab 2 values from my `config.ini`, which is in `/settings/config.ini` and run a bash script with the variables.

```
[wifi]
ssid = myssid
password = myssidpass
```

**script.sh**

```
ssid=$(awk '/^ssid/{print $3}' /settings/config.ini)
pw=$(awk '/^password/{print $3}' /settings/config.ini)
./wifi -ssid "$ssid" -pass "$pw"
```

When the config.ini resides in the same folder path, it finds the variables. As soon it's outside the script path it does not work. How can I tell awk to get it from the full path?
Thanks

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: what 'does not work'? the extraction of the desired values from the ini file? or does the `./wifi` call fail?

Comment: Oh, i fixed it now. It works.It was permissions.